# How to disable Tap gesture (all interaction) in UIView and its subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, tap, interaction

I have 2 classes cellView(basically a cell with tap) and Board view With 64 cellViews.
From my VC i want to disable/enable  all interactions on them on certain event.
this is my code.

```
if(currentGame.isYourTurn==NO){
    [divBoardView  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    for(UIView*currentView in  [divBoardView  subviews]){
        [currentView  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
} else ..
```

and in cell view is just view with

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

I want to disable and enable interaction without adding and deleting tapGestureRecognisers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to iterate `[divBoardView subviews]` and set each one's `userInteractionEnabled` property. Simply setting this property on the parent view, in this case `divBoardView` will disable interaction for all subviews.

With that being said, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` should not be attached to `divBoardView` or any view that you're planning on disabling, as it will not fire if `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO`.

Depending on your design, it may be better to attach the gesture recognizer to your viewController's `view` property:

```
// Where self is the view controller
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

And process interaction based on some state:

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isBoardActive;

@end



@implementation 

- (void)handlerTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    UIView *viewControllerView = tap.view.
    CGPoint location           = [tap locationInView:viewControllerView];

    if (_isBoardActive && CGRectContainsPoint(_boardView.frame, location)) {
        // Process tap on board   
    } else {
        // Process tap elsewhere
    }
}

@end
```

This is just one solution. It is difficult to recommend the ideal solution as there is very little information provided with regards to your problem. There are many more ways of accomplishing the same thing and the best alternative will depending on your current app structure, design, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The property of `userInteractionEnabled` works for all subviews in the view that you set the property on.

Same with tap gesture recognisers. If you add a recogniser and set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` then the recogniser will never get fired.

So, you should be able to do...

```
divBoardView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This will work recursively through all subviews (not really but it will have the same effect) and also disable any recognisers.

Then...

```
divBoardView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Will enable everything again.

Comment: omg man thanks. I found my lame mistake.I was calling this before init of boardView.This code works perfectly